# Android Sliding Puzzzle Game: the slide effect

Tags: android, slide, puzzle

I'm trying to make an Android puzzle game out of a picture.
What i've done 'till now is:
-i've cut the picture in how many parts i get from the EditText field;
-i've put the cut pictures in a gridview and got a puzzle table;
-i've also used the Collection.suffle(list) to suffle the images in the gridview;

Now, i am trying to implement the sliding effect on two images from gridview. So what i want to achieve is a sliding effect similar to CandyCrush app or this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUoP87fNB8w . I mean, i want to hold an image and drag it top so it should slide top. If i click the picture and slide bottom, it should change with the picture below it and so on...

Here is my code:

```
        Reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BReset);
    SplitNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edSplitBy);
    SplitBy = Integer.parseInt(SplitNo.getText().toString());
    ImgNo = SplitBy * SplitBy;
    puzzle = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.puzzle);
    rootImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.source_image);
    splitImage(rootImg);
    formPuzzle(smallimages);
    Reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Reset.setText("Reset");
            SplitNo.getEditableText().toString();
            SplitBy = Integer.parseInt(SplitNo.getText().toString());
            ImgNo = SplitBy * SplitBy;
            Collections.shuffle(smallimages);
            formPuzzle(smallimages);
        }

    });
```

And here is how i form the puzzle:

```
private void formPuzzle(ArrayList<PuzzleItem> smallimages) {

    SMI = new SmallImageAdapter(this, smallimages);
    puzzle.setAdapter(SMI);
    puzzle.setNumColumns(SplitBy);
    puzzle.setHorizontalSpacing(0);
    puzzle.setVerticalSpacing(0); }
```

PuzzleItem.class:

```
public class PuzzleItem {
Bitmap puzzlepartImage;
int correctPosition;

public PuzzleItem(Bitmap d, int index) {
    puzzlepartImage = d;
    correctPosition = index;
}
```

I used this class just to remember the position of the pieces so i can check if the puzzle is finished...

So i'm only interested in how to implement the sliding motion by draging an item from gridview...

Thanks :)

EDIT: Should i use an OnTouchListener ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've managed to find the solution by myself :

```
private void formPuzzle(final ArrayList<PuzzleItem> smallimages) {

    SMI = new SmallImageAdapter(this, smallimages);
    puzzle.setAdapter(SMI);
    puzzle.setNumColumns(SplitBy);
    puzzle.setHorizontalSpacing(0);
    puzzle.setVerticalSpacing(0);

    puzzle.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
                smallimage_Position = puzzle.pointToPosition((int) startX,
                        (int) startY);
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                Log.d("X", "..." +endX);
                Log.d("Y", "..." +endY);
                if(endX > startX + smallimage_Width/2 && (endY < startY - smallimage_Height/2 || endY < startY + smallimage_Height/2) ){
                    PuzzleItem p1 = SMI.smallimages.get(smallimage_Position);
                    PuzzleItem p2 = SMI.smallimages.get(smallimage_Position +1);
                    SMI.smallimages.set(smallimage_Position, p2);
                    SMI.smallimages.set(smallimage_Position +1, p1);
                    SMI.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    startX = endX*200;
                    startY = endY*200;


                }
                return true;
            }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The slide is given by the MotionEvent.Action_MOVE and by calculating the pixels you can find out in what direction is the finger moving ... For example .. the if from my Action_Move case is recognising a swipe to the right ...

I hope this will help some of you guys ...

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about achieving slides in a slider puzzle game is to use a game engine. I recommend [Cocos2D for Android](http://denvycom.com/blog/setting-up-cocos2d-for-android-in-eclipse/), and theres a detailed tutorial on that here ...

http://denvycom.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-build-your-first-slider-puzzle-game-in-cocos2d-for-android-part-1/

Comment: link contains viruses

Comment: Sorry about that @Rasel . At my end here, it appears the link loads fine. Can you kindly explain more on the nature of virus you encountered ? Thanks. (I also used a couple url scanners to quickly check the link e.g http://www.urlvoid.com/)

Comment: yesterday i tried to open both of links, then my avast antivirus blocked it and says trozan blocked